# Node.js: Make a HTTP POST with params

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, twilio

```
call = "https://aaa@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/sasa/Calls.xml"
fields = { To : "+12321434", From : req.body.from }

request.post 
  url: call, body: fields (err,response,body) ->
    console.log response.body
```

How can I pass fields to the HTTP POST request?

It works if I pass a string like `"To=+12321434"` but not `"To=+12321434,From = req.body.from"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stringify your data, look at the example:
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/querystring.html#querystring.stringify